# Save a 1 row, 1 field query directly into a variable instead of using while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

If you have a query like

```
SELECT max(customerID) FROM customers
```

Is there a way to save that directly to a variable instead of using

```
$results = $dbLink->query("SELECT max(customerID) FROM customers");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $maxID = $row['customerID'];
}
```

The latter is just a lot of type for 1 value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy - just don't use loop:

```
$results = $dbLink->query("SELECT max(customerID) FROM customers");
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
$maxID = $row['customerID'];
```

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Would it be `$results['customerID']` since row wasn't defined due to the loop being dropped?

Comment: @mhopkins321: `$results` is a resource that is used to fetch the data from. It doesn't hold the data itself. See it yourself with `var_dump($results);`

Comment: ah, sorry. I missed the `$row = ` part of that line. I'm dumb